# Why is non-greedy character not acting 'non-greedy'?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-greedy

I'm working with a regex in javascript.

I have this regex: `/\/.+?$/`

and this string: `/path/to/file`

I am expecting to get `/file` as a result but instead am getting the entire string back. What am I not understanding here? The `?` should make the `+` non-greedy, meaning it will match the fewest possible characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions will always try to match left to right.  Even though `.+?` is non-greedy, the regex will still try to match from the beginning of the string if possible and only advance the starting position when the match fails.

You have a couple of options to fix this:

- Include a greedy match at the beginning of the regex so that your match will always start as far into the string as possible, and use a capturing group to grab what you want.  The regex here might looks something like `/.*(\/.+?)$/`, and then you would get `/file` as the contents in the first capturing group.
- Change the regex so that the `.+?` can't match any additional `/`, so it would be `/\/[^\/]+$/`.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. I was forgetting that regex matches left to right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negation for your need:

```
'/path/to/file'.match(/\/[^/]+$/);
//=> ["/file"]
```

Your regex `/\/.+?$/` is matching first slash and then matching rest of the input using `.+?` since there is nothing following `.+?`.

You can see different behavior if you use: `/\/.+?\/$/` which will behave reluctantly and match `/path/`.

Answer (score 0):

The `$` at the end of your expression forces a compulsory end-of-string match. The only way to do so is to grab the entire string, greedy or not.

However, your regex is flawed even *without* the `$`. `/\/.+?/` will match just one character, where the entire string is matched by `/\/.+/`. You don't specify any constraint at all.

To grab only the first part, up to -- but excluding -- a next slash, use this:

```
/\/.[^\/]*/
```

Comment: `/\/.+?/` will not match the entire string, but only `/p`.

Comment: @MichaelMior: thanks for the heads-up; I just realized that myself.